# Retrieve XY data from matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm writing a little app in wxPython which has a matplotlib figure (using the wxagg backend) panel.  I'd like to add the ability for the user to export X,Y data of what is currently plotted in the figure to a text file.  Is there a non-invasive way to do this?  I've searched quite a bit and can't seem to find anything, though I feel like it is incredibly simple and right in front of my face.

I could definitely get the data and store it somewhere when it is plotted, and use that - but that would be fairly invasive, into the lower levels of my code. It would be so much easier, and universal, if I could do something as easy as:

```
x = FigurePanel.axes.GetXData()
y = FigurePanel.axes.GetYData()
```

Hopefully that makes some sense :)

Thanks so much!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

**edit**: to clarify, what I'd like to know how to do is get the X,Y data.  Writing to the text file after that is trivial ;)

Comment: I swear I googled every possible combination of words that I could think of, but did not come across that thread!  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I only found that by googling for 'matplotlib get_xdata', not with the standard search of SO.

Comment: Just FYI: In general, matplotlib plotting functions return an `Artist` instance (or sequence of artists, in the case of `plot`) that contains the data, styling information, etc.  Many artists have `get_data` and `set_data` methods (e.g. you can do `x, y = line.get_data()`).  For some, the method may be called something else (e.g. `scatter` returns a collection where the equivalent method is `get_offsets`) A few artists (`ContourSets` for example) don't contain references to the original input data, but this is quite rare.  Basically, you want to hold on to the output of plotting functions.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This works:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x30b2b10>]

In [3]: ax = plt.gca() # get axis handle

In [4]: line = ax.lines[0] # get the first line, there might be more

In [5]: line.get_xdata()
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [6]: line.get_ydata()
Out[6]: array([4, 5, 6])

In [7]: line.get_xydata()
Out[7]: 
array([[ 1.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  6.]])
```

I found these by digging around in the axis object. I could only find some [minimal information](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_xdata) about these functions, apperently you can give them a boolean flag to get either original or processed data, not sure what the means.

**Edit**: Joe Kington showed a slightly neater way to do this:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: lines = plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10])

In [3]: lines[0].get_data()
Out[3]: (array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]))

In [4]: lines[1].get_data()
Out[4]: (array([7, 8]), array([ 9, 10]))
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  For future readers, I'll also add in that     line.get_label()    also returns the label associated with the line object ;)  Thanks again!

Comment: Why doesn't a `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D object` have `get_zdata()`? I can't extract the z values. :-(