# How to get the coordinates from weibull curve using spicy, python

Tags: python, highcharts, scipy, weibull

I'm new with python,scipy and stats in general.
I want to get the coordinates (x,y) from an 'weibull curve' (I do not know if the expression is correct...).

Input : lambda, beta,...
   output: (0,0),(2,3),etc...

I want use this output to graph multiple series by using HighCharts, because this is part of a webservice, for now I only need the coordinates.

Thanks.

OS: fedora

Comment: Hey Ros; you will need to explain that Weibull is a distribution and you need to provide your code snippets and much more context for people to be able to assist you well. People here are general engineers and do not necessarily have context on Scipy or statistics.

Comment: Are you referring to [this one](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.weibull.html)?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What, exactly, is a *Weibull curve*?  Is it the PDF of the Weibull distribution, the CDF, or something else?  Is one of the curves shown on the [wikipedia page for the Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm so sorry...I just find the solution, The 'curve' doesn't  really matter....I only have to get  data before plot, the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130768/retrieve-xy-data-from-matplotlib-figure

Comment: I will considerate your advice plumSemPy , I thought that tags 'scipy' and 'weibull' were enough...