# Save bezier curve to a file in python

Tags: python, bezier

I am using [bezier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bezier/0.3.0) to generate a Bezier curve. Below is the sample code:

```
import bezier
nodes = np.array([
     [0.0 ,  0.0],
     [0.25,  2.0],
     [0.5 , -2.0],
     [0.75,  2.0],
     [1.0 ,  0.3],
 ])
curve = bezier.Curve.from_nodes(nodes)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
curve.plot(num_pts=256)
plt.show()
```

Please see below the generated plot.
[image]

I want to save this trajectory (let say to a file). In other words, I want to save x,y value of each point in this curve. I was expecting it to return a numpy array but it is not. kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax = plt.gca() 
line = ax.lines[0]
x = line.get_xdata()
y = line.get_ydata()
xy = np.vstack([x,y]).transpose()
np.save('bezier_data', xy)
```

I worked it out from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130768/retrieve-xy-data-from-matplotlib-figure?noredirect=1&lq=1). Those `xvals` and `yvals` are NumPy arrays you can put them into one if you need it.

Might help to not execute `plt.show()` before these lines.

Comment: Thank you so much!