# How to extract xy-data from Julia plots?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am using the `contour` function from Julia's `Plots` to plot level curves. I want to extract a list of `x` coordinates and a list of `y` coordinates corresponding to the level curves from the plot, e.g., something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130768/retrieve-xy-data-from-matplotlib-figure). Is there a way to do it in Julia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for `contour`, unfortunately. For most plot types you can extract the input data of, e.g. the first series in the first subplot, with `p[1][1][:x]`. But for contour in particular Plots does not generate the level curves, it simply passes the matrix to the backend that then does the computation and display.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!