# Retrieving data from pyplot using geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gis, geopandas

I'm trying to avoid saving a matplotlib figure to file, just to recall it and preprocess the image for a tensorflow model. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130768/retrieve-xy-data-from-matplotlib-figure) which made me optimistic, unfortunately, geopandas has an inbuilt plotting function. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Ideally, I would like a numPy image array of the intensity values of all points

```py
data = gp.read_file('/path_to.shp')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

lines = data.plot(ax=ax)
print(lines[0].get_data())
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GIS2img.py", line 108, in <module>
    print(lines[0].get_data())
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
```

I would like to get RGB image data in an array for each figure

I would appreciate any help, thanks

Edit: Clarified question

Comment: Text and code are somehow contradictory. It's hence not clear if you want to get the data, or if you want an RGB  array of the complete axes.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like an RGB array of the complete axes. Will update question

Comment: See, e.g. [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/agg_buffer_to_array.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the help.

You can draw to a canvas using: `fig.canvas.draw()` and then retrieve that image using `np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)`.