# How to extract data from a 'AxesSubplot' made by Prophet model

Tags: python, matplotlib, facebook-prophet

I made a time series model using prophet and I want to find the exact date of the maximum of the yearly trend revealed by the plot made by the `m.plot_components(forecast)` function.

However I'm not sure how to extract it from the plot.
from prophets examples [page](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api):

```
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
df = pd.read_csv('../examples/example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv')
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
forecast = m.predict(future)
fig2 = m.plot_components(forecast)
```

fig2.axis[2] is an 'AxesSubplot' object and it comes from a 'matplotlib.figure.Figure' (fig2). How do I get out the arrays that make up the line inside that subplot object?

Comment: From this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130768/retrieve-xy-data-from-matplotlib-figure
Use `ax.lines[0].get_xdata()` and `ay.lines[0].get_xdata()`

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, it gets the value of the graph object. `fig_child = fig2.get_children();fig_child[1].lines[0].get_ydata()`

Comment: Worked great! Thanks all!